# Report containing sums from different queries in Access

Tags: ms-access

I am currently working with different tables and queries in Access and I can't find a way to do something very simple. I have the following :

- Two queries, qry1 and qry2
- One table, tbl1

Both queries and the table have a "NET" field of type float (or double)

What I'd like to do is create a very simple report which would give me the total of the NET column for each of those three objects. I have tried to insert a text box in a blank report and selecting sum(NET) on qry1 in Control Source but it doesn't work, it simply prints '#Error' with no more information.

If I use 'Add Existing field' and drag&drop 'NET' from tbl1 and then edit it to add sum it works but it is repeated for each row which is obviously not what I want. It feels like I'm missing something here or that I might not be using the right tool.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you gather the sums of "NET" into a single query and use that as the report's data source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered the `DSum()` function?  Create three text boxes and set the control source for each text box as follows:

```
=DSum("NET", "qry1")
=DSum("NET", "qry2")
=DSum("NET", "tbl1")
```

---

*Note: Aggregate functions (e.g., `DSum`, `DLookup`, etc.) have poor performance compared to performing the calculations within a query. It's not clear from your question whether that's an option for you or not.*

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed !